# Should I use a recyclerView inside a recyclerView or is there a better way?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a query which returns all logEntries for a specific exercise.

[ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmiWa.png)

Each log entry has:
`log_id`
`total_weight_lifted` and `reps` .

I would like to display the results of this query in a recyclerView like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x54O9.jpg)

How is this best achieved?

Should I create a recyclerView inside another recyclerView, or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: you mean recyclerview inside the view holder of recyclerview ? yes you can do that , alternatively you can set a clicklister on the view holder and then open another fragement/activity which shows that data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesting of recylcers is generally a bad idea. This is bad for performance.

You might want to create RecyclerView with multiple view types. One for category title (for example "Tuesday, March 17" from your screenshot) and a second one for rep ("110 kgs 1 reps")

Here is stackoverflow post on how to create RecyclerView with multiple view types:
[How to create RecyclerView with multiple view type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)

If it helped please mark as answered.